# Would magnets work outside the magnetic field of planets?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, space

Would magnets work in outer space, but very far from any planet or star, outside their magnetic fields? And electro-magnets?

Would they still repel each other? If so, would it be with much less force or almost the same force?

Comment: You might read; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetosphere#Earth's_magnetosphere

Comment: Also; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field

Comment: @AdrianHoward Thanks, if you could please be more specific, I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: I posted an answer, hope it helps, but reading; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature Also; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetism and the previous links may give you a better understanding.

Comment: The compass won't work obviously, but a permanent horseshoe magnet will still have a magnetic field around it

Answer (score 2):

The following may be useful.

Permanent magnets don't require external magnetic fields in order to operate.  If you have regular "horseshoe" magnets or fridge magnets, they will work in outer space the same way as they do on Earth.  Electro-magnets would also work the same way in outer space.  The forces of all these magnets would be the same in outer space as here on Earth.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer! and do you know how much time does it have to pass until they start loosing their force of repulsion significantly? (provided they are being permanently repulsed on purpose by forcing their poles to stay close one another) months or rather years?

Comment: this question and answers may interest you https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14667/how-long-does-a-permanent-magnet-remain-a-magnet/14681#14681

Comment: Thank you Anna !!

Answer (score 1):

As far as we know the properties of magnetic and electromagnetic forces are universal. Their properties are the same in space as they are on Earth. The magnitude of Earth's magnetic field at the surface is around 25 to 65 microteslas. This is weak enough to usually not be noticeable in many ordinary magnet uses, unless very precise interactions or measurements are necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Applying an electric current to a conductor leads to the occurrence of a noticeable magnetic field around the conductor. A stronger magnetic field you get by winding a wire into a coil and applying a current to the coil. Using this time a material with unpaired electrons or protons in their molecules it is probable that after the switch-off of the current a magnetic field remains. On the other hand, applying a strong enough current or doing the procedure with a cooled down coil you also will measure a magnetic field after switching off the current.

All these phenomena together with the phenomenon of permanent magnets have their origin in the existence of magnetic dipoles. Electrons, protons and even neutrons are tiny magnets. Usually the magnetic dipoles of the subatomic particles are oriented randomly in space. Applying a current or an external magnetic field, the magnetic dipoles get aligned and a lot of materials show a magnetic field.

Once magnetized only some materials don’t loose the magnetization again. These we call permanent magnets. And we have some interesting facts which tells us, why some materials by room temperature are permanent magnets and other not:

1. Lowering the temperature more and more materials became permanent magnets.
2. On the other hand, rising the temperature the magnetization gets lost in any case.
3. Materials with unpaired electrons are easier to magnetise than materials with paired electrons.

It turns out that thermic vibrations in materials at some level destroy the alignment of the subatomic magnetic dipoles (see 1. and 2.). And it turns out that paired subatomic particles neutralize their magnetic dipoles.

In the comments you asked

> ... how much time does it have to pass until they start loosing their force of repulsion significantly?

This is not a matter of time. The destruction of the macroscopic magnetic field is carried out by rising the temperature of the body or applying a short-term external magnetic field.

> Would magnets work outside the magnetic field of planets?

The magnetic field of the earth is weak in comparison to permanent magnets. Perhaps you are referring your question to the theory that permanent magnetic materials on earth are magnetized by the earths magnetic field. May be, but than together with the melting of the material. After cooling down the alignment of the magnetic dipoles remains. Short answer: The magnetization will not be destroyed.