# Aluminum channel profile vs. extruded plastic with custom magnet

Tags: electromagnetism

I have a patented product ready for manufacturing. I am wondering if aluminum would be the better choice instead of extruded plastic?

Will the magnet lose its strength over time and become demagnetized, if aluminum is used? The custom magnet has already been made.

The magnet being used is Neodymium-Rare Earth (Zn coated).

The maximum magnetic field strength observed at distance of 2.1m is 0.00126 Gauss, less than 0.00525 Gauss.

[image: Invention]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do magnets lose their magnetism?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8036/)

Comment: I think your post could be better received on http://engineering.stackexchange.com .